# How to disallow 'cd ..' for a chroot user

Tags: permissions, chroot, webserver, cd-command

I wanted to restrict a user from accessing files (just outside his directory), so I used chroot, and made the restricted directory as his landing directory upon logging in.
But, If I do `cd ..` that user can access everything outside his directory too. How to avoid this?

I used this:

```
adduser --home Rest_folder --shell /bin/bash --no-create-home --ingroup www-data --ingroup ssh rest_user
```

Comment: How did you setup the chroot?

Comment: chown -R rest_user:www-data rest_folder, is it wrong, Sir?

Comment: "chown" isn't "chroot". It doesn't appear that you're actually using chroot here.

Comment: see `man rbash`

Comment: @cas `rbash` is trivial to break, unfortunately. Unlike `rsh`, which sets up the signal handling correctly.

Comment: @roaima are you talking about the restricted Bourne Shell or about the remote shell?

Comment: @schily sorry, I thought that was obvious from context. The restricted Bourne shell.

Comment: Does this user login remotely via SSH (easy to set up, because you can use SFTP) or locally (bash binary with all its dependencies has to be within chroot, complex to set up)?

Comment: @rexkogitans User logins remotely using SSH. But, I found configuring ssh and chrooting a bit complex (I read in another post how wrong chrooting could break the system, so didn't do anything and came here immediately) and therefore did not do anything exce[t the command above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SSH, it is possible to use its subsystem called SFTP (not to be confused with FTPS). SFTP provides a shell where the user can do any common file task like `cp`, `mv`, `ls`, `cd`, `mkdir`, `rm`... However, other programs that reside in `/bin` are not accessible this way because of the chroot environment. This chroot environment is setup by the SSH daemon, so there is no need to struggle with details.

To configure a chroot for a certain SSH user, put this into the sshd config file, mostly located at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User rest_user
  ChrootDirectory /home/rest_user
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

You may wish to set other flags for this login, too:

```
  AllowTCPForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

For more details, see the man page of `sshd_config (5)`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help!